# Finding a range of p values for which the integrals converges

Tags: calculus, integration

[Image of the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyzjz.png)

I know that $$
\int_1^2 \frac{dx}{x(\ln x)^p} 
$$
and $$
\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(x) dx}{x^p}
$$
each converge if and only if $p<1$, but I do not understand why. When I input into the calculator, the integral converges even $p>1$ as long as p≠1. So why is it $p<1$ instead of $p\ne 1$.

Answer (score 1):

I have got a answer, although it is not rigorous enough if that is what OP wants.
$$\int_{0}^{1}x^{-p}\ln(x) \mathrm dx$$
First evaluating the Indefinite Integral Using Integration By Parts:
$$=\frac{x^{1-p}\ln x}{1-p}-\frac{1}{1-p}\int x^{-p} \mathrm dx$$

$$=\frac{x^{1-p}\ln x}{1-p}-\frac{x^{1-p}}{(1-p)^2}$$
Notice how as we are integrating $x^{-p},p \neq 1$ as the integration will then give $\ln(x)$.

The Definite Integral:
$$\left( \frac{1^{1-p}\ln 1}{1-p}-\frac{1^{1-p}}{(1-p)^2} \right)-\left( \frac{0^{1-p}\ln 0}{1-p}-\frac{0^{1-p}}{(1-p)^2} \right)$$

We have $0^{1-p}$ which means $1-p>0$ as we wouldn't want the $0$ in the denominator.
This implies $1>p$
Finally it will be evaluated as:

$$-\frac{1}{(1-p)^2}, p<1$$

$$\int_{1}^{2}\frac{1}{x(\ln x)^p} \mathrm dx$$
This integral can be solved by letting $u=\ln (x)$

$$\frac{(\ln x)^{1-p}}{1-p}$$
The definite integral then becomes:

$$(\frac{(\ln 2)^{1-p}}{1-p})-(\frac{(\ln 1)^{1-p}}{1-p})$$
$\ln (1) = 0$, using similar logic $1-p>0$
Therefore,
$$\frac{(\ln 2)^{1-p}}{1-p}, 1>p$$